# Scaling fonts with css

Tags: css, fonts

What is the correct way to scale a font using css. And what about compatibility? Maybe it would be better to customize the font file itself?

For example i need to scale Avenir font 116% vertical scale and 105% horizontal scale.
          [image: Scaling Avenir font]

Comment: Have you looked at letter-spacing? this will not achive the full result you are looking for but maybe a bit on the way trying to do it with css. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/letter-spacing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to

**HTML**

```
<p>
 Hello
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
display:inline-block;
transform:scale(1,4); 
-webkit-transform:scale(1,4); 
-moz-transform:scale(1,4); 
-ms-transform:scale(1,4); 
-o-transform:scale(1,4); 
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yk5s8pdy/)**

You can change the scale(x,y) value according to your need considering you are changing the height and width differently (i.e the ratio of Height:Width is not 1:1)

Comment: Thank you changing the values `transform:scale(1.05,1.16); ....` did the job. I'll just have to find out about compatibility

Comment: @AivarasP These are universal to all modern browsers. -Webkit- takes care of chrome, -moz- takes care of Mozilla and so on

Answer (score 1):

Two points for you.

Editing the Avenir font itself infringes the font license, you need to get permission from the font foundry for that.

Second never stretch fonts, it looks so bad. When you stretch a font it messes up the stroke widths, horizontal strokes will become thinner than the vertical strokes and when you squish a font up the vertical strokes become thinner than the horizontal ones.

So my answer is there is no correct way to do it.

If you need a condensed font there are plenty available for example:

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed

Answer (score 0):

I usually use em scaling for font because it automatically adjust to the current font size. Maybe this [reference](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) could help you to know about font-size scaling. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

we can adjust by increasing the size of font like font-size:40px; and adjust it through line-height